# Node.js (express.js) : куки-монстр съедает все печенье!

Tags: node.js, cookie, javascript, http, header

Вопрос может показаться странным, но вот изучаю я тут Node.js и в частности express.js. С этой проблемой уже покапался в инете, но решения не нашел. Вот есть код, простейший и cгенерированный express:

```
var express = require('express')
, routes = require('./routes')
, user = require('./routes/user')
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080 );
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('short'));
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

//app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.cookie('cart', 'test', {expires: new Date(Date.now() + 300), httpOnly: true});
    res.send("Ok");
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Результат есть, видно "Ok", а вот куки нет. Проверял в chrome. Почему нет куки?

ТАААААК!!! ПЕРЕФОРМУЛИРУЮ ВОПРОС!!!!

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var app = express();

app.listen( 8080 );

app.get( '/', function( req, res ){
    res.cookie('cart', 'test', {expires: new Date(Date.now() + 300), httpOnly: true});
    res.send("Ok");
} );
```

Тут у меня куки появились, по этому вопрос другой! Кто знает почему их не было в примере номер 1, но есть в примере номер 2???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Куки-монстром оказался я сам!

new Date(Date.now() + 300) - оказывает я делал быстро-порчущиеся печенье, которое никому не нужно...